# Can I set an image as a grid item?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-grid

I have grid with 3 elements like this:

[image: this]

Now I want to replace blue elements with images (could be just dummy images).**

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(30em, auto);
  justify-items: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.grid-item-1 {
  background: url("https://editzstock.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/broken-text-300x300.png");
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.grid-item-2 {}

.grid-item-3 {
  grid-column: span 2;
  grid-row: span 1;
}

.grid-item {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  background-color: #379AD6;
  color: #222;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-1">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-2">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: there is a typo, this is why it don't work ❌`.gird` ✅`.grid`

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qf1zN.jpg works fine

Comment: I made you a snippet. I had to change gird to grid a few times

Comment: Do you want them as imgs or as background-images?

Answer (score 0):

Speaking just from experience over the past 7 years, images as grid / flex items often glitch in one way or another.

The glitch is almost always resolved by nesting the image in a container, making the container the grid / flex item.

Although images are valid as grid / flex items, until the various browsers make some more progress on this issue, I would suggest you use a container (thus keeping the images in a block formatting context).